# Get header text of all sections of a Word document

Tags: office-js

I want to make a table of headers of all sections using `office.js`. I can not get the header text from a section. There are a method in section object that returns body object. How can I get the header text from that body object ?

```js
sectionObject.getHeader(type);
```

Here is my code:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        //Create table here            
        var sections = context.document.sections;
        context.load(sections);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (sections != null) {
                    var items = sections.items;
                    var itemsCount = items.length;                        
                    for (var i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                        var currentSection = items[i];
                        var headerBody =currentSection.getHeader('primary');
                        //Get headerText here
                        //??


                        //Write the text into table
                    }                        
                }

            }).catch(function (myError) {                    
                showNotification("Error", myError.message);
            });

    }).catch(errorHandler);
```

Please ignore table create/write comments.

I have tried a way: getting `paragraph collection from the body object. Then get the first paragraph text. That is actually the header text. In that case I have to load and sync the paragraph collection to get the item. Now, If I load and sync the collection into a loop, loop go through only once so that I get header only for one section. But I need headers of all sections. Here is the code:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        //Create table here  
        var sections = context.document.sections;
        context.load(sections);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (sections != null) {
                    var items = sections.items;
                    var itemsCount = items.length;                        
                    for (var i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                        var currentSection = items[i];
                        var headerBody = currentSection.getHeader('primary');
                        var headerBodyParagraps = headerBody.paragraphs;

                        context.load(headerBodyParagraps);
                        return context.sync()
                        .then(function () {
                            if (headerBodyParagraps != null) {
                                var headerBodyParaItems = headerBodyParagraps.items;
                                var headerText = headerBodyParagraps.items[0].text;

                                //Write the headerText into table
                                //
                            }

                        });
                    }                        
                }

            }).catch(function (myError) {
                //otherwise we handle the exception here!
                showNotification("Error", myError.message);
            });

    }).catch(errorHandler);
```

I tried another way. Instead of loading "headerBodyParagraps" once for each section, add the "headerBodyParagraps" in a array and load all of them at a time. But loading a array of collections throws error: Cannot use the object across different request contexts. Here is code:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        //Add table here 
        var sections = context.document.sections;
        context.load(sections);
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (sections != null) {
                    var items = sections.items;
                    var itemsCount = items.length;
                    var paraList = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
                        var currentSection = items[i];
                        var headerBody = currentSection.getHeader('primary');                            
                        var headerBodyParagraps = headerBody.paragraphs;
                        paraList[i] = headerBodyParagraps;                           
                    }
                    context.load(paraList); // Throws exception("Cannot use the object across different request contexts ") here.

                    context.sync()
                    .then(function () {
                        if (paraList != null) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < itemsCount; j++) {

                                var headerBodyParaItems = paraList[j].items;
                                var headerText = paraList[j].items[0].text;

                                //Add headertext to table here 
                            }
                        }

                    });

                }

            }).catch(function (myError) {
                //otherwise we handle the exception here!
                showNotification("Error", myError.message);
            });

    }).catch(errorHandler);
```

Thanks for reading. Any types of tip/help is welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the header text is available, you need to `load` & `sync` to retrieve it.  For example:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
    var currentSection = items[i];
    var headerBody = currentSection.getHeader('primary');
    context.load(headerBody);
    context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log(headerBody.text);
    });
}
```

From a performance perspective, this will generate a bunch of unnecessary `sync` calls. A better option would be to leverage the queue so you request head header but fetch all them in one `sync` call:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    var sections = context.document.sections;
    context.load(sections);
    return context.sync().then(function () {
        if (sections != null) {
            // Collection of headers we'll populate later
            var headers = [];

            // Iterate through the sections 
            for (var i = 0; i < sections.items.length; i++) {

                // Grab the header from the current section
                var header = sections.items[i].getHeader('primary');

                // Add loading this header to the  queue 
                context.load(header);

                // Push this header into the headers collection
                headers.push(header);
            }

            // Sync/Exectute the queued actions
            context.sync().then(function () {
                // Iterate through the headers collection
                for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                    // Output each header's text to the console
                    console.log(headers[i].text);
                }
            });

        }
    });
})
```