# how to add different header inside second page of word using JavaScript office API word office add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am new to the creation of an Office add-in using yo office generator, I have created a word office Add-in that will insert a custom header and footer based on the command clicked. I was able to add a header and footer on the first page successfully. But I want to add a different header on the second page.

Like eg Page 1 Header is ABC
Page 2 Header should be DEF
Page 3 Header should be DEF

Below is the code that I followed to add the first header and footer

```
`Office.initialize = function () {
  // Entry point for the add-in
};

function addHeaderAndFooter() {
  Word.run(function (context) {
    var section = context.document.sections.getFirst();
    section.load("header", "footer");

    return context.sync()
      .then(function () {
        var header = section.header;
        var footer = section.footer;

        header.insertText("Header text", Word.InsertLocation.start);
        footer.insertText("Footer text", Word.InsertLocation.start);

        return context.sync();
      });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may find the following post helpful - [Get header text of all sections of a Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45937441/get-header-text-of-all-sections-of-a-word-document)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the same. but it's not working. First page is working find but i want add different header on the second page.